# Как сделать ipip tunnel между серверами linux?

Tags: linux, vpn, tunnel, ipip

Есть 2 сервера linux (debian\centos)
Нужно сделать между ними ipip или vpn туннель, что бы "передать" ip с одного сервера на другой.
S- сервер
S1 123.123.123.123
S2 222.222.222.222

Нужно, что бы на S1 в интерфейсах отобразился "новый ip", подключенный через туннель (222.222.222.222)
Но, что бы он отображался не как локальный 192.168.0.3 или 10.10.10.1, а именно 222...

Читал статьи: netwild.ru/linuxipip
https://debian.pro/1578

Но в них требуется, что бы на сервере-доноре было 2 ip (один из которых можно передать). А мне нужно сделать такой туннель (или "передать" ip), имея только по одному ip-адресу на серверах.

P.S:Сервера в разных сетях и имеют статические ip.

Как такое можно реализовать? Заранее спасибо

Comment: А если из интернета кто то шлет пакет на ip 222.222.222.222 то этот запрос должен поступать на обработку запущенной программе на первом сервере или на втором ? Как система должна это понимать, если ip на двух машинах ?

Comment: если из интернета кто-то шлет пакет на 222.222.222.222, то пакет поступает на 222.222.222.222.

Но программа, которая работает на сервере с 123.123.123.123 отправляет пакеты "в интернет" через 222.222.222.222. Она работает только на исходящем трафике и ей не нужно получать ответов.

Comment: Эммм ... что значит "работает только на исходящем трафике", она шлет исключительно UDP пакеты и они должны уходить с этого 2.2.2.2 ? и никаких ответов она вообще не получает ?

Comment: неа. К примеру через 25 порт отправляет почту. Исходящий трафик идет из 123.123.123.123 на 222.222.222.222(хотя сервер S1 думает, что это его ip) и затем уже письмо идет к адресату (ему отображается 222.222.222.222).

Comment: Вы понимаете, что письмо отправляется по протоколу TCP и ему необходим двухсторонний обмен трафиком. При отправке письма отправляющий посылает запросы на что сервер принимающий почту ему шлет ответы, хотя бы о том принял он почту или нет. Следоватльно обратный трафик будет. И чем вас не устраивает стандартное решение с 192.168 на туннеле и маскарадинге исходящих пакетов на сервере 2.2.2.2 (маскарадинг - подмена адреса отправителя в пакете) ?

Comment: когда задавал вопрос - что-то мудрил с dns и думал, можно ли его как-то поднять через ip, который получен таким образом. Сейчас понимаю, что тема с dns отпадает, так как это не возможно, по этому можно вернутся к 192.168.    Пойду почитаю про маскарадинг. А можно как-то реализовать маскарадинг, если донор ip, это vpn-server, а принимающий сервер подключает этот ip посредством pptp? Тогда создается интерфейс с 192.168 и, по идее , все должно получится

Comment: Маскарадинг делается просто: ёiptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -s 192.168.... -o имя-интерфейса-где-интернет -j MASQUERADE`  все, сервер сам поймет что надо сделать адрес 2.2.2.2 т.к. он у него стоит на исходящем интерфейсе. Останется только настроить маршрутизацию на отправляющей машине, что бы она слала пакеты в туннель, а не просто в интернет

Comment: P.S. Но вообще то, что вы изначально спросили возможно. Я не зря ни в одном комментарии не употреблял слово "невозможно", а спрашивал как отличить одни пакеты от других. Просто настройка такой схемы с учетом правильных критериев отличия пакетов будет очень нетривиальной и запутанной, плюс те еще извраты с маршрутизацией, что бы часть пакетов машина перестала считать "своими". И в 99.999% случаев такое не нужно

Comment: Вот скрин ifconfig : http://joxi.ru/eAO500DT49E5lm

туннель добавлен, но почта не отправляется через него. Если на внешнем адресе туннеля закрыт 25 порт, как я смогу через него отправлять почту?

Comment: Это что за туннель такой ? чем вы его поднимали ? Это очень похоже на алиас на интерфейсе а не на туннель, т.е. он не заворачивает пакеты в внешнюю оболочку. И почему на нем ip который приходится затирать на картинке, т.е. не внутренний

Comment: Через час где то вернусь, напишу как понимать видимо ...

Comment: я добавил vpn-туннель через pptp, ребутнул сервер и в etc/network/interfaces создался новый интерфейс:
iface eth0:0 inet static
 address 89.***.***.24
 netmask 255.255.255.255

Comment: Странный у вас vpn, pptp обычно поднимаем ppp интерфесы. А у вас на этом "интерфейсе" даже счетчиков пакетов нет. Он не настоящий, а просто алиас на на eth0. А вы попробуйте попингуйте с одной машины другую по ip которые на этих интерфейсах. Только перед этим `rounte -n` посмотрите, убедитесь, что ip который на vpn с другой стороны туннеля есть в маршрутизации отдельной записью

Comment: В ответе написал для туннеля ipip, если у вас vpn вдруг все таки рабочий, можете просто правила маршрутизации/фаервола взять и поставить в них нужные ip

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на уточнения вопроса в комментариях к нему. Потому как решение вопроса "как есть" представляется не целесообразным. Пишу на скорую руку, без стендов ...

Дано: 2 сервера, смотрящие в интернет и имеющие реальные ip адреса, стоящие на интерфейсах `eth0`. Сервер S1 с ip 1.1.1.1 должен отправлять почту (и возможно что то еще) таким образом, что бы она реально уходила со второго сервера. Второй сервер S2 с ip 2.2.2.2

Конфигурация S1 (отправляющий почту):

```
#!/bin/sh
## ip tu add tunl1 mode ipip local 1.1.1.1 remote 2.2.2.2    # создаем туннель
## ifconfig tunl1 192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 pointopoint 192.168.2.2

iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j MARK --set-mark 0x2 # маркируем пакеты исходящей почты
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 1.1.1.1 -o tunl1 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.2.1

# Создаем во 2й таблице маршрутизации маршрут по умолчанию ведущий через туннель
ip route add tab 2 default via 192.168.2.2 src 192.168.2.1
# добавляем политику маршрутизации пакетов помеченных маркой 2 через 2ю таблицу
ip rule add prio 100 fwmark 0x2/0x2 lookup 2
ip route flush cache  # Сброс кеша маршрутизации. Перестраховка. В стартовых скриптах системы можно не делать
```

Конфигурация сервера S2:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward  # разрешаем проброску трафика через систему (если не включено в /etc/sysctl.conf)
##ip tu add tunl1 mode ipip local 2.2.2.2 remote 1.1.1.1
##ifconfig tunl1 192.168.2.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 pointopoint 192.168.2.1

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.1 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE # Все пакеты идущие из туннеля в интернет маскарадим в наш внешний ip
```

Просмотр туннелей `ip tu`, удаление туннеля `ip tu del tunl1`. Просмотр конкретной (2й например) таблицы маршрутизации `ip ro li tab 2`, просмотр политики маршрутизации `ip ru`, удалении конкретной политики `ip ru del параметры-правила`

Comment: я немного тупил и не правильно создал туннель. Сейчас все перенастроил. Вот скрин ifconfig: http://joxi.ru/ZrJEOOph1wWKxA

Я не могу на сервере, у которого "беру ip" ничего делать. Сервер выступает в роли vpn-сервера(S2), к которому я подключаюсь через pptp(S1). На S1 поднимается новый интерфейс ppp0 192.168...
Задача: отправить почту с S1 через ip S2 (192.168...) Порты на S1 закрыты (25/587...)

Пробовал отправить через 192.168 и через внешний адрес S189.***.***.24 - не отправляется. Даже не пойму в чем проблема

Comment: Ну тогда `ip tu` и `ifconfig` мои не используете, остальное вам понадобится, вам же я так понял трафик в туннель надо по номеру порта направлять, вы же ip-адрес назначения изначально не знаете

Comment: P.S: приношу извинения, с момента постановки вопроса немного изменились цели и теперь не нужно делать туннель ipip или подобные между серверами. Теперь нужно сделать такое: имея лишь vpn-сервер(S1), который отдает ip и сервером(S2), который подключается через pptp, openVPN или иным другим способом к S1.

S2(почтовый сервер)->S1(VPN server)-> получатель почты.

Такое реализовать возможно?

P.P.S: на S1 порты для отправки почты закрыты.

Comment: В моем примере S1 и S2 местами поменяйте, ip tu, ifconfig выкеньте, tunl1 на свой ppp0 замените и должно работать. Если конечно 25 порт не закрыт iptables на самом же сервере S1, но что то мне подсказывает, что он закрыт где-то у прова, так что должно работать

Comment: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTNG -i ppp0 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE ////
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Comment: Ой, буковку пропустил POSTROUTING

Comment: Неа, это я недосмотрел, так как команда echo 1 не внесла изменения в файл, пришлось руками менять значение. После этого новая проблема, найти в интернете ответ не смог:

iptables v1.4.14: Can't use -i with POSTROUTING

Comment: Хм. любопытно. я для упрощения так написал, не думал, что там интерфейс уже не известен ... короче. меняем этот ключ на -s 192.168.x.x тот IP который по другую сторону туннеля, т.е. с которого пойдет пакет. Надеюсь он пойдет именно с него. Еще он может пойти с реальника того сервера, тогда нужно будет для надежности такое же правило с тем реальником

Comment: Сделал, это ничего не изменило. Отправка почты по прежнему идет с основного ip сервера. В качестве ip для отправки указан основной ip сервера (этот же ip на котором стоит домен на сервере). Если указать для отправки 192.168.10.2 (в моем случает), то выдает ошибку: 
...T=remote_smtp defer (-53): retry time not reached for any host  - не возможно соединиться..

P.S: все это уже после настроенного маскарадинга

Comment: Но это значит, что пакеты скорее всего не ушли в туннель. можете посмотреть `tcpdump -n -i ppp0` будет показывать трафик идущий в туннеле. Если не ушли в туннель, значит на той стороне не сработала маршрутизация. А если они в туннеле с реальником своим то точно маскарад надо написать исходя из ip с которого они идут. Да, маскарад если что пишется уже на конечном сервере, с которого пакеты уже в интернет уйдут

Comment: ... Я думал, маскарад пишется на сервере, который отправляет пакеты на "внешний сервер".  Как я писал раньше, нету возможности прописать маскарадинг на конечном сервере. Так как он служит только как vpn сервер...
S1 (linux;почтовый сервер;dns)-IP1 --> S2 (vpn-server)IP2..


Задача: Отправить письмо с S1 через IP2

P.S: как тут ставить отступы между строк(enter)? А то все в одну строку сливается :(

Comment: А маршрутизацией на этом vpn то же играться не получится, в смысле всякие ip ro, ip ru ?

Comment: А программы там нельзя устанавливать, например тот же sendmail или другой MTA (почтовый сервер) ? И что почту на первом сервере собственно шлет. Какой то МТА или скрипты ? Если MTA то какой

Comment: На сервере VPN вообще ничего не выйдет сделать, так как там даже ОS как таковой нету. Ни линукс, не винда. Вот создался туннель и все, больше ничего...

На S1 стоит ispmanager, отправка почты идет с через roundcube. Хотя я могу установить что-угодно, лишь бы работало. Могу создать smtp и рассылать через windows софт...

Comment: А вы на тот VPN как попадаете ? тупо web-инерфейс или ssh есть ?

Comment: Конечно, web интерфейс есть. Открыты 80 8080 порты

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33161/discussion-between-mike-and-bossuvarkin).

Answer (score 0):

в описанном виде, насколько мне известно, это неосуществимо.

---

представим на минуту, что это каким-то образом удалось реализовать: пакет для второй машины инкапсулируется — «заворачивается» внутрь другого пакета, чтобы «уйти» по созданному туннелю.

но какой адрес назначения должен быть у «пакета-обёртки»? тоже *ip-адрес* второй машины!

и, значит, его тоже нужно «завернуть» внутрь ещё одного пакета. и так до бесконечности. и никаких полезных данных при этом так и не отправится.

Comment: Ну вообще это не совсем так, уже завернутый в оболочку пакет можно отличить по протоколу обертки или номеру порта, выставить на нем fwmark, на основании которого применить другую политику маршрутизации и выпустить пакет наружу. плюс к этому придется поменять приоритет таблицы маршрутизации local и добавить собственные таблицы перед ней. Но, с "неосуществимо" вы погорячились

Comment: @Mike , так напишите правильный ответ. так, чтобы им воспользоваться мог и, к примеру, автор вопроса.

Comment: Автору это не нужно, уже выяснили, что внутренних ip и маскарада для его задач достаточно. А городить еще тот паровоз извращений из за задачи, решаемой стандартными средствами не стоит. Так что правильный ответ "не делайте так" :)

Comment: @Mike , поразмышлял над вашим планом. по-моему, «не взлетит», разве что ещё с какими-нибудь (возможно, существенными) ограничениями. но и тратить время на попытки построить «паровоз извращений» мне тоже не интересно.

Comment: Ну я собственно лично для вас и писал, просто что бы не было грани "не возможно". Я когда то, когда в linux еще не было нормальных средств для резки скорости по сумме вход/выход делал что то подобное, что бы и входящий и исходящий трафик прошли через 1 туннельный интерфейс в одном направлении и потом ушли в сеть. оно было рабочим. но делать стенд и отрабатывать, для никому не нужного ответа, да, времени жалко.

Answer (score 0):

В таком случае у вас S2 это шлюз для выхода в интернет. Между S1 и S2 можно настроить VPN, используя приватную подсеть, а запросы перенаправлять к S1 по заданным правилам, настроив маршрутизацию. Когда на S2 поступает входящий запрос, если он удовлетворяет определенным условиям, то перенаправляется на обработку на S1 через VPN. Далее S1 обрабатывает запрос и отдаёт ответ через цепочку S1-VPN-S2-internet.

А назначить один и тот же внешний IP на двух разных серверах, как уже отметили в комментариях, нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, я что-то не до конца понял из вопроса: вы хотите назначить конкретные адреса p2p (Point-to-Point) туннелю?

Это возможно сделать следующим образом:

- Сконфигурировать vpn (Например, с помощью ssh)
- Назначить tun-интерфейсу необходимый вам IP.

PS: Вашему tun-интерфейсу вы можете назначить абсолютно любой IP-адрес. Но важно понимать, что при этом могут возникнуть проблемы с наложением адресов (К примеру, вы заняли публичный IP-адрес в вашей локальной сети, и сервер больше не сможет правильно маршрутизировать трафик к реальному владельцу).

Comment: Ответ должен быть самодостаточным. Не стоит сводить его к ссылке на свой блог. Если можете привести полное решение - приведите его прямо в теле ответа.

Comment: В таком случае это будет сочинение на свободную тему. Этот ответ нужно воспринимать как возможный вариант решения. В случае если человек заинтересуется этим решением он посмотрит как это можно сделать. Тем более, познания по этой теме требует целого пласта познаний в администрировании.