# Можно ли сделать дополнительный ip из прокси?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, proxy

Есть сервер, на нем поднимается дополнительный интерфейс eth1 и он получает ip из туннеля. Что-то на подобии такого:

```
   auto tun4to4
   iface tun4to4 inet4 v4tunnel
   pre-up modprobe ipv6
   address 199.88.99.22
   netmask 16              
   gateway 199.88.99.1
   endpoint any
   local 182.192.99.128
```

Такое можно сделать использовав vpn-туннель или pptp соединение, но как такое сделать с проксей?

Задача: есть прокси 111.111.111.111:1111. нужно сделать так, что бы весь исходящий трафик с сервера шел через этот прокси + прокси должна выступать как сетевой интерфейс.

Comment: А что за проксти ? web, soccks или еще какая. Если web - то вы сможете прокинуть только tcp трафик и то при условии что она поддерживает команду connect. socks может и udp но опять же зависит от настроек.

Comment: прокси будет любая, какую скажете. В основном socks, но можно и http достать. Вы мне помогли в настройке через pptp. Огромное спасибо за это. А сейчас я хочу узнать, можно ли сделать так же, только через прокси.

Первоначальная тема:
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/475501/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-ipip-tunnel-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-linux

Comment: *прокси будет любая, какую скажете* — тогда ответ: да, можно сделать «дополнительный ip». ведь я же могу сказать: пусть это будет такой прокси, через который можно сделать «дополнительный ip». а откуда вы возьмёте такой прокси — это уже **ваши** проблемы.

Comment: а ответ по адекватней можно? Есть 4 вида прокси: hhtp, https, socks4 и socks5, которые можно достать без проблем. С этими прокси как это сделать?

Comment: Ну вот, например. https://habrahabr.ru/post/116360/ вообще в гугле по запросу "прозрачный socks" или "прозрачный прокси" много можно найти